# Visual studio 2013 attach to process taking long time

Tags: debugging

I am working on VS 2013.WHen i am trying to attach to the process ,it is taking more than 1 minute to attach all class libraries.

I have tried removing temporary files, disabling browser link and some other options also.
Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Well, that does sound like **Microsoft** *shudder* Visual Studio... Out of curiosity, are sure that the program is compiling quickly? Maybe the majority of the minute is the compile time. Read the console and watch the messages.

Comment: Ashwin,The compilation is very quick.I have sitecore CMS running on my local machine which is a third party system and looks like the dlls from sitecore are taking long time to attach.The problem is i can not remove them.Not sure other options that are interfacing the attch process.

Comment: hmm, not sure what to do about that. You should try editing that onto the question and also maybe set a bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unchecking the microsoft symbol server , and deleting the existing symbols in provided directory, the issue got resolved.

[image].com/uRvlj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed "Powershell Tools for Visual Studio", then uninstall it from tools -> extensions and updates.. This will solve the attaching long time in VS-2013